# After log transforming my data to have equal variances for ANOVA, do I use the new p-values of the transformed data?

Tags: anova, variance, data-transformation

When running one-way ANOVA I did not have equal variances, so I log transformed the data and reran ANOVA with equal variances. Do I use these new p-values from Tukey's post-test on my graph showing the raw data? Or do I keep the old p-values from my raw data? One comparison is more significant with the transformed data than it was with the raw data, so am wondering whether to change my * to *** in my graph.

Comment: You want want to report $p$-values based on your transformed data.  The whole reason for transforming the data was so that your data would be approximately normal so that you can obtain the appropriate $p$-values using the normal pdf as your reference pdf.

Comment: However, if the transformation is chosen by looking at the data, the properties of the corresponding p-values will be at least somewhat impacted by that data-based model choice.

Comment: I would instead say that you should not have changed your data, you should have changed your model.

Comment: There is a point of view in which taking logs does not change the data: it changes only how the data are *expressed.*  Because the re-expression is nonlinear, though, it can be construed as changing the model (as noted by @PeterFlom) when ANOVA is applied to the logs.  In particular, Tukey's post-hoc test on the ANOVA of the logs compares *geometric means* of the groups rather than *arithmetic means* of the groups: thus, even the hypothesis is changed.  You haven't mentioned checking that taking logs was appropriate, either, so you ought to do that before going any further.

Comment: @whuber I don't understand the distinction between "change the data" and "change ... how the data are expressed". I mean, sure, you are leaving the data in place, but you aren't using them.

Comment: @Peter I cannot conceive of what you might mean by not "using" the data when you analyze their logarithms!  To explain, let's consider the related problem of encoding a nominal variable, such as gender.  Although there are many valid ways to do this--for instance, male as 0 and female as 1 or male as 1 and female as 0--the *data* don't change.  Only the numbers one works with will change.  The same thing occurs for any variable, such as (say) the observations of a thermometer.  One is free to choose different ways to mark the thermometer positions with numbers: that is merely re-expression.